# Is there a method to figure out the audio channel layout in Linux?

Tags: linux, audio, channel, alsa

I'm making a player for Linux and I want to know the audio channel layout (stereo, 5.1ch, etc) of user's system (not channels included in media file).
For now, it's set by user but I want to implement an auto-detection of channel layout.

Is there any (de-facto) standard method to accomplish this?
If not, can I find a solution for ALSA at least?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ALSA, the `default` device typically supports only stereo.
You can try to open a device named `front`, `surround40`, `surround51`, or `surround71`, but these devices do not have automatic sample format conversion or software mixing.

The best idea would be to use PulseAudio, and to ask the server for the channel map of the sink.